# xhr.setRequestHeader() merging my headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, request-headers

I want to add header to my xhr.

When I use setRequestHeader, what it actually does is adding a value to Access-Control-Request-Headers.

If I code:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('key1', 'value1');
xhr.setRequestHeader('key2', 'value2');
```

What I see in the request header is:
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, key1, key2

What i expect to see instead is:

key1: value1

key2: value2

How can I prevent this merging?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're making a non-simple cross-domain XMLHttpRequest ([read more about CORS here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)) which means that your browser must send an preflight (`OPTIONS`) request prior to your intended request. This is done to verify with the server that the client from a different origin is allowed to make said request. When you are making a CORS request the browser will automatically add the `Access-Control-Request` headers to the request when it gets sent.

The `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header is a comma-delimited list of non-simple headers that are included in the request. The only "simple" headers you can set are: `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Content-Language`, `Last-Event-ID`, and `Content-Type` (if it is set to one of: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`).

The server must respond to those `Access-Control-Request` headers in the preflight request with the corresponding `Access-Control-Allow` headers in its response. So in your case it would need to respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: key1, key2`.